# How to count and sum entries per each group?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the dataframe:

```
GROUP   TIME  EVAL
AAA     20    0
AAA     22    0
AAA     21    1
AAA     20    0
BBB     20    0
```

I want to see how many entries belong to each grouping and how many entries have `EVAL` equal to 1 in each grouping. I have almost finished the code, but just not sure how to count entries per group. It seems to search for a column `TOTAL_CALLS`, while I want to create it.

```
final = df.groupby(['GROUP']).agg({'TIME':'mean','EVAL':'sum','TOTAL_NUM':'count'}).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `lambda` and sum `boolean mask`:

```
final = df.groupby(['GROUP']).agg({'TIME':['mean', 'size'],
                                  'EVAL': [lambda x: (x == 1).sum(), 'sum']})
final = final.rename(columns={'<lambda>':'size_of_1'})
final.columns = final.columns.map('_'.join)
final = final.reset_index()
print (final)
  GROUP  EVAL_size_of_1  EVAL_sum  TIME_mean  TIME_size
0   AAA               1         1      20.75          4
1   BBB               0         0      20.00          1
```

Comment: Where do you count the number of rows per group?

Comment: I want to create the column `TOTAL_NUM`, because it does not exist. In this column I want to put the total number of rows belonging to particular group. For example, `AAA, 21, 0, 4`, where `4` is the number of times that this combination appears. So, in this example `TOTAL_NUM` is `4`.

Comment: Maybe I should use `value_counts()` or something like `.size().to_frame('TOTAL_NUM')` ?

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I need 4 columns as an output, but numerical values are correct.

Comment: Ok, please check my solution and if something wrong let me know. Thanks.

Comment: But one question. Why `AAA` appears only once in the result? For `AAA` and `EVAL` equal to `0` (sum is 0) the value of `TOTAL_NUM` should be equal to `3`, while for `AAA` and `EVAL` equal to `1` (sum is `1`), the value of `TOTAL_NUM` should be equal to `1`.

Comment: Hmmm, I amnot sure if understand, do you need count of values `0` and count of values `1` ?

Comment: No problem, nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Using the `Time` column itself, we can calculate both number of records and mean time for each group. This can be achieved by sending a list ['mean','count'] for the aggregation. we could find the sum of `Eval` for each group as well.

```
  print(data.groupby(['Group']).agg({'Time':['mean','count'],'Eval' : 'sum'}).reset_index())


  Group Eval   Time      
         sum   mean count
0   AAA    1  20.75     4
1   BBB    0  20.00     1
```

Comment: This looks like it answers the question. Could you provide a little more written explanation? That would help both the OP and the quality of your answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
df:
    EVAL GROUP  TIME
0  0     AAA   20  
1  0     AAA   22  
2  1     AAA   21  
3  0     AAA   20  
4  0     BBB   20     

# group by 'GROUP'
gb = df.groupby('GROUP')

# aggregate each column by method
final = gb.agg({'GROUP': 'count',
                'EVAL': 'sum',
                'TIME': 'mean'})

# rename columns and reset index
final = final.rename(columns={'GROUP': 'GROUP_TOTAL',
                              'EVAL': 'EVAL_COUNT',
                              'TIME': 'TIME_AVG'}).reset_index()

out:
  GROUP  EVAL_COUNT  TIME_AVG  GROUP_TOTAL
0  AAA   1          20.7500    4          
1  BBB   0          20.0000    1
```